# iOS 6 native Facebook/Twitter login info

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, ios6, slcomposeviewcontroller

I want to add Facebook/Twitter posting in my app using SLComposeViewController in iOS6 and I just want to add a check if the user is already logged in to Facebook/Twitter on device. So my question is that is it even necessary to add this sort of a check? Does iOS 6 handle this automatically? If I do need to add it, how can it be done? I've looked around a bit but I can't find much help on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's a bug, but if the user has not set up a Twitter/Facebook account on their device already, it will not appear in the UIActivity action sheet.

With the stock iOS 6 Apple apps, this bug doesn't exist, so when the user taps on Twitter on the action sheet and if they haven't set up an account yet, a UIAlert will come up and ask the user if they wish to go to Settings to configure a new account. Unfortunately 3rd party apps don't get this until or IF the bug is fixed.